# Checking if location services are enabled. [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using the following observable object to track the users location:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var location: CLLocation? = nil
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationServicesEnabled() -> Bool {
        return self.locationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile I get an error next to the `return self.locationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` statement. The compiler says: `Static member 'locationServicesEnabled' cannot be used on instance of type 'CLLocationManager', Replace 'self.locationManager' with 'CLLocationManager'`. I do not understand this error because `self.locationManager` is an instance of `CLLocationManager`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Static means that locationServicesEnabled is a member of the class, not of the object. Use the classname CLLocationManager as suggested.

Seems like the API has changed, earlier it was an instance method, now it is a class method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620566-locationservicesenabled

Comment: I've realized that what I actually want to do is check whether the app is authorized to use location services. Is there a similar method to do this?

Comment: yes :p https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3563952-authorizationstatus

Answer (score 0):

static func configureLocationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate?) {

```
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    manager.delegate = delegate
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
    
    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.requestLocation()
        }
    default:
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Here a piece of code that configured location manager and checks whether the app was allowed by user to use location services.

Here is more code that could be useful. This is a file that I created to implement the delegate methods.
https://github.com/aibo-cora/Safe-Bavaria/blob/main/Safe%20Bavaria/View%20Model%20-%20Utility/Find.User.Location.swift